# how to add files in svnserver using linux

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn

I am creating a svnrepository using svnadmin create svndump

In the svnsump I am creating a folder with the name trunk and importing some of my existing files.

svn import /home/somefiles/ file:///home/svndump/trunk/

But when i see trunk folder it does'nt contains any folder which are imported from somefiles folder.

but when i looked the files using  svn log file:///home/svnadump/trunk/  i can see the files .

it seems files are copying but they are not adding to the repository..

how to add files to repository???

Please help me..

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [svn ls](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html) to view the contents of repository.

For adding files to repository once you have imported, the standard way is to checkout a copy, add some files using 'svn add' and them commit them to the repository.

Comment: Thanks sud : when i am importing the files into repository the folder's are not adding to repository..in general when u add are create a folder in linux they will be displaying in blue color. but when i import the files into repository they are displaying as jus folders ..i,e they are not adding reposiory